# Grails Entity constrain

Tags: grails, grails-orm

This is my user entity.. Why my lastlogin is not null in database? i have aLready set blank to true.

```
class Users {


static hasMany = [farm:Farms,report:Reports,reportMessage:ReportMessages]

String userName 
String Password
Date LastLogin
String userImage

static constraints = {
    userName (blank:false, unique:true)
    Password (blank:false)
    userImage (blank:false)
    LastLogin (blank:true)

}
```

}

Comment: may be of memory leak issue restart pc and check again code is all right and drop database and create again

Comment: @HelpMeToAskQuestions that is remarkably bad advice. I'll give you the benefit of the doubt and attribute it to ignorance rather than malice

Comment: sir i have been facing same problem so what i found to sort this is the above can you suggest me the better solution for this

Comment: can you explain how restarting a PC would cause a field in the database to change from non-null to null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there's a bug. Change `LastLogin` to `lastLogin` and solves the issue.

Comment: Seems very unlikely to me, but if you're sure, I'd encourage you to raise this issue in the Grails bug-tracker so that others don't have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

If you want `LastLogin` to be nullable, you should use the constraint

```
LastLogin (nullable:true)
```

rather than

```
LastLogin (blank:true)
```

> Why my lastlogin is not null in database? i have aLready set blank to true.

Adding one of the constraints above does not mean that it *will be* blank/null, it means that it *can be* blank/null.

The reason it is not null in the database is most likely because you're assigning a value to it, before the `Users` object is saved.

Comment: @user974459 then you should create a test that reproduces nullable not working, and open a bug (with the test attached) in the Grails bug tracker. However, I'm 99.999% sure that nullable does work and equally certain that the problem is somewhere in your code rather than a Grails bug.

Comment: But it is the database column that cannot be null

Comment: Assuming your database is in synch with your domain model, if you add the constraint `LastLogin (nullable:true)` the corresponding column in the database can be null. If you remove this constraint, it can not. If you're certain you're observing behaviour inconsistent with this, open a bug in the Grails bug tracker